# Accept an untrusted certificate by default to connect with SSL for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application I need to accept an untrusted certificate by default to connect with SSL, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an project on Codeplex that allows you to trust otherwise untrusted root CAs.
It's called [Windows Phone Certificate Installer](http://wp7certinstaller.codeplex.com/), and you can re-use the `TrustedRootCertificateInstaller.cs` file in your projects.